# ...Your baby gonna come out naked

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains, jokes, southern-white-vernacular-english

I heard this in a casual how-to video. It seemed random and not associated with anything they were doing. Someone said, "My favorite one is... your baby is going to come out naked. If you keep working around those chemicals, your baby is going to come out naked."

What is the history and application of this phrase or pun? The film was made in Georgia, so I suspect it has a southern origin.

Comment: I couldn't find any sources on it but my guess is it means "nothing will happen" since babies always come out naked. I suspect there's a joking aspect to it since "your baby will come out [bad thing]" is common.

Comment: The broader notion that being born naked is a metaphor for the ultimate egalitariinism of the human condition is noted in works at last as early as _Honour and vertue, triumphing over the grave_ (1640): "Pertinently to this _S. Ambrose, We are born naked, saith he, and die naked, & there is no difference between the car casses of the rich, and the poore, save that the former stinke worse through a repletion with excrements, which surfets of delicious fare have left behinde_." [St. Ambrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose) lived circa 340–397, so this is a very old observation indeed.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Because it makes the title shorter.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Look at the title closer.